# Delete Every Word After The First Word Including Space From Multiple Columns In Python

Tags: python, replace, split

I have this dataframe called 'food' which looks like this

| Calories / Column A | Protein / Column B | Cholesterol / Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 330.0 kcal | 5.0 g | 10.0 mg |
| 26.0 kcal | 16.0 g | 36.0 mg |

I want to delete all words (including space) behind the number so that i could change the column type as float like this

| Calories / Column A | Protein / Column B | Cholesterol / Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 330.0 | 5.0 | 10.0 |
| 26.0 | 16.0 | 36.0 |

I've tried to use replace, slice, split, and regex. replace and slice didn't work, but if i use split i need to do it manually for every columns. I've tried to copy regex from internet souce but i'm not sure why it didn't work.  I'm planning on using iteration (for) to automate split function and join it again for the next trial. My question is, is there any ways that much more efficient? Thank you so much

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: @Malcolm yes...

Comment: Welcome to SO, irene G. Please copy and paste as text the code you have tried. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help for information about how to ask questions.

Comment: `df.replace(' .*', '', regex=True)` should do the trick if there is always a space after the number.  Note the regex is space-period-asterisk, meaning a space character followed by zero or more of any character.